# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hasLocationPermission - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am creating an app using react native. I would like to get the users location using [react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service).

I have followed the setup as documented on GitHub. When I try to run my app within iOS I get the following error.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: hasLocationPermission

Here is my code

```js
const hasLocationPermission = async () => {
  const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
    PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.LOCATION,
    {
      title: 'Cool Weather App',
      message: 'Cool Weather App needs access to use your location',
      buttonNegative: 'Ask Me Later',
      buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
      buttonPositive: 'OK'
    }
  );
  if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    console.log('You can use the app');
  } else {
    console.log('Location Permission Denied');
  } (error) => {
    console.warn(error);
  }
}

    componentDidMount() {
    if(hasLocationPermission) {
      Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          console.log(position);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000}
      );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    }
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing code or doing something wrong.

UPDATE:

I have fixed the Reference Error and am now facing a new error.

> ERROR  Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: That example is assuming you checked/requested permission. Check out docs here https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid

Comment: Yeah, I can't seem to get that working and I have no idea why

Comment: You may want to rewrite the question with what you tried to get the permissions...

Comment: @becky how are you checking if the user has granted location permission or not? That's what `hasLocationPermission` is supposed to be.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check location permission like this:

```js
class deneme extends Component {
    hasLocationPermission = async() => {
        const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.LOCATION, {
            title: 'Cool Weather App',
            message: 'Cool Weather App needs access to use your location',
            buttonNegative: 'Ask Me Later',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            buttonPositive: 'OK'
        });
        if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            console.log('You can use the app');
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log('Location Permission Denied');
            return false;
        }
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            _isLocationEnabled: false
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        hasLocationPermission().then(result => {
            this.setState({_isLocationEnabled: result});
        });
    }

    render() {
        { this.state._isLocationEnabled ? (
            <View><Text>Permission Enabled!</Text></View>
        ) : ( <View><Text>Permission Disabled!</Text></View> )}
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting  "Can't find variable: hasLocationPermission" again